# Debugging K2 workflow - how to view data associated with error conditions?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity, k2

I have a K2 Blackpearl workflow.  In the workflow I populate a process data field with email addresses pulled from a SharePoint list.  Using the Text - Join function with the SP List's SmartObject's GetList method for the values and a semi-colon for the separator.

In theory, this should produce a well-formatted string with multiple addresses for the "To" line of the E-mail event.  However, I keep receiving a "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address." at the point where the workflow should attempt to send an email.

I've tried using the string  "john.doe@company.com;jane.dove@company.com;abc.def@company.com" directly and I've tried splitting the string on the semi-colons in the Activity's destination set.  In the first case, there is one instance trying to send the email.  In the second instance, the emails are resolved to users and though I select the "ActivityInstanceDestUserEmail" for the "To" line, I still get the error message.

We are using K2 Blackpearl 4.6 with a SharePoint 2010 farm configured strictly for Claims authentication.  The users to which I wish to send the email have valid email addresses if resolved using the K2SPS provider, but when the emails are resolved into destination slots, they are resolved into accounts with the K2 provider.  I'm guessing that this is the problem with my second method for sending the email.  But the first, putting the whole string in the "To" line should have worked it is straight email addresses - no resolving to users is needed.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes in the configuration of our customer security provider, labelled "K2SPS" seem to have resolved the problem - at least for now.